# Fonts in custom SVG node Image with vis.js network

Tags: vis.js-network, vis.js

I'm looking for nodes that are circles with a font-icon in the middle and the stock label below.  This (http://jsbin.com/hiqega/3/edit?js,output) is really close to what I'm looking for except that I need to pass the font name and the icon code to use.

```
function nodeImage(color, icon, font)
{
  var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ' +
                 'width="120" height="120" viewPort="0 0 120 120">' +
            '<ellipse ry="55" rx="55" cy="60" cx="60" ' +
                 'style="fill:' + color + ';stroke:black;stroke-opacity:.5;stroke-width:4;" />' +
            '<text x="61" y="63" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" ' +
                 'style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:100px;fill:black;fill-opacity:.5;">' +
                 icon + '</text>' +
            '</svg>';
  return 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg);
}
```

I'm calling this like so `nodeImage('red', '&#xf03d;', 'FontAwesome')` in a page that is already using the font elsewhere so I don't think the issue is that it's not loaded.

[Here's a pic of the resulting node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLnmP.png)

Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: (Doesn't look much different from the result from jsbin: how would a/the SVG renderer know about the font named?)

Comment: I tried adding <defs> and <style> tags to the SVG to define the `@font-face`.  The resulting SVG properly renders using FontAwesome or my own icon font when viewed in the browser stand-alone but still gives me the empty block placeholder when I try to use it as the `image` for the vis.js network node.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write nodeImage('red', '\uf03d', 'FontAwesome'). http://visjs.org/examples/network/nodeStyles/icons.html

"Remember! Unicode in javascript is done like this: \uf274 for the unicode f274. 
If a node is shown as a rectangle, it means the css is not loaded (or not yet loaded). A redraw will fix that."